# MVC 4 OutputCache with different client server durations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, outputcache

How can I have a server OutputCache Duration of 2 minutes and a browser cache expiration of 10 minutes, oh and specifically have it work in IE 8?

```
[OutputCachce(Duration=120,VaryByParam="*"]
```

and then in the action I set

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10));
```

It seems as long as I have the attribute it ignores what I set on the response in the action (except the OmitVaryStar that works). I've also tried using AddHeader and setting the Cache-Control, and again it works without the attribute but with it, its ignored\overridden by the attribute. I'm returning a FileContentResult if that matters.